# Updating to TinyMCE 4 - Image Features

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have just updated to TinyMCE 4 in our CMS, to be used by a number of different clients.
While it mostly offers new and improved features, the insert image tool feature seems to be lacking compared to the previous version of TinyMCE.
Previously there was 3 tabs of abilities for people to manipulate the image, but now there is no way to alter the title, alignment, border, spacing, adding a class in particular.

I have setup TinyMCE 4 using the image plugin, but wondered if there was anyway to customise the basic initialisation to add these features back in?